# Too much logic in view for MVC pattern?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, model-view-controller

This is my HTML template for adding a new user:

```
<div layout:fragment="content">
<div th:if="${#request.getParameter('successful') != null}" class="card m-3">
    <div th:if="${#request.getParameter('successful') == 'true'}" class="card-body text-white bg-success">
        <span th:text="#{employees.add.succesful}"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card m-3">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h4 th:text="#{employees.add.title}" class="card-title"></h4>
        <p th:text="#{employees.add.subtitle}" class="card-subtitle text-muted"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/employees/add}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label th:text="#{employees.add.first_name}" for="first_name"></label>
                <input th:placeholder="#{employees.add.first_name}" th:errorclass="is-invalid" th:field="*{firstName}" type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" th:errors="*{firstName}"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label th:text="#{employees.add.last_name}" for="last_name"></label>
                <input th:placeholder="#{employees.add.last_name}" th:errorclass="is-invalid" th:field="*{lastName}" type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}" th:errors="*{lastName}"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label th:text="#{employees.add.email}" for="email"></label>
                <input th:placeholder="#{employees.add.email}" th:field="*{email}" th:errorclass="is-invalid" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}"></div>
            </div>
            <p><button th:text="#{button.submit}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></button><button th:text="#{button.reset}" type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary"></button></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Does it contain too much logic? We're trying to stick to the MVC pattern, which means, we can't afford too much logic in the view.
If you think there is too much logic in it, how can we improve it? Which parts can be moved into Java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **logic** you don't want in MVC pattern is **business logic** and I don't see any business logic in your code so you can't improve it in that sense